How do we know that Apple watch is connected with Apple Health Kit?
I'm new to Apple Health Kit, I have implemented Apple Health kit to my iOS App.
I just want to know that is there any API or any other ways to find Apple watch is connected to Apple Health Kit?
Thanks in Advance.
I've checked documentation for Apple Health kit, but didn't find anything useful.

Are you trying to figure out if the iPhone your app is running on has an Apple Watch currently connected to it or are you trying to figure out if a specific Health Kit measurement is coming from the Apple Watch or not?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes, I will give proper info about this.
